# How do I create source folders in Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Basically my problem is I have :

> c:\blah\blah\myApp\webapp\some_javascript.js
>
> c:\blah\blah\common-js\webapp\some_common_javascript.js

I want **some_javascript** to access **some_common_javascript**, but because Webstorm uses absolute paths there is a conflict with **myApp** and **common-js**.

I want a single project that recognises \webapp\ as being the source folder for both!

My concrete example is :

(1) I debug/run :

C:/developer/eclipse/workspaces/ilean/supportagentCockpit/src/main/webapp/index.html

(2) I get these errors :

> ```
> ReferenceError: Page is not defined   C:/developer/eclipse/workspaces/ilean/supportagentCockpit/src/main/webapp/js/ilean/page/PermissionPage.js:1
> ReferenceError: Page is not defined   C:/developer/eclipse/workspaces/ilean/supportagentCockpit/src/main/webapp/js/ilean/page/DevicesPage.js:1
> ReferenceError: Page is not defined   C:/developer/eclipse/workspaces/ilean/supportagentCockpit/src/main/webapp/js/ilean/page/LogFilesPage.js:1
> ```

(3) The errors pertain to my index.html at this point :

```
<script src="js/ilean/page/PermissionPage.js"></script>
<script src="js/ilean/page/DevicesPage.js"></script>
<script src="js/ilean/page/LogFilesPage.js"></script>
```

(4) The Page has also been imported in my index though..

```
<script src="js/toolkit/Page.js"></script>
```

(5) On the file system is lives here :

> C:\developer\eclipse\workspaces\ilean\iLeanWUITemplate\src\main\webapp\js\toolkit\Page.js

whereas my other stuff lives here :

> C:/developer/eclipse/workspaces/ilean/supportagentCockpit/src/main/webapp/js/ilean/page/*

(6) So basically, if you treat everything under src/main as being in the same project/module it would work, BUT because one is in directory **iLeanWUITemplate** and the other is in the **supportagentCockpit** dir, they cant see each other.

In Eclipse I got it working because they both run in the same container

Answer (score 2):

Open File > Settings. On the left hand side choose "Directories" under the "Project Settings" header. On the right hand side pane you should see just your `myApp/webapp` directory under the "Add Content Root" button:

[image]

Click the button and add the `common-js/webapp` directory as a new content root.

Comment: yes, but when i run it, ie, i say "run in browser" it goes to c:\blah\blah. Ahhhh I guess my question really is, how do I run my application in a container?

Comment: @OliverWatkins: You can set up the run/debug configurations to do whatever you want, so I don't see how that is a problem. What do you mean "run in a container"?

Comment: Hi Jon, i wrote in a concrete example to the question. Do you think you know the answer?